# Fancybox loads php page, NOT on a floating window though

Tags: php, redirect, fancybox, floating

my purpose is to load in a floating window a php page that redirects my user to Twitter to sign in and then invites his followers through that same window. Hopefully fancybox can handle this. With the code below the php is loaded and getting redirected to Twitter, however this is not happening on a floating window, but on the main page itself. Here's my code, am I missing something? I tried a lot of recommendations from other question to even get it to this point.

```
<li onclick="inviteTwitters()">
    <a class="fancyelement fancybox.ajax" href="#" data-id="http://kokas.x10.mx/wp-content/themes/childoftwentytwelve/twitter/redirect.php">
        span>Twitter</span>
    </a>
</li>

function inviteTwitters() { 
    $(".fancyelement").click(); 
}

$('.fancyelement').click(function() {

    var myUrl = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.fancybox(
        {
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 600,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '70%',
            height      : '70%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            href        : myUrl
             }
        }
    );

    return false;
});
```

Comment: What kind of output does your page debugger show?

Comment: This may be pedantic, but did you load *both* the jQuery library and the fancybox plugin, [as shown here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions)?

Comment: @SuperJer I don't know what you mean by page debugger, clicking the link redirects to me here https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=fHSEjyiVnvUoU7QqjfzZIC6v00iV9UBDqKFp8dOtgo

Comment: Chrome has a nice built-in debugger that you can use by hitting F12.  Firefox also has a built-in debugger, but most would agree that its Firebug addin is superior.  Any of these debuggers will be able to display ajax calls, network requests, etc., including all the data that is sent/received for each.

Comment: I got this error on firebug: Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=FpM6gQl2cngPZj9hDVhxr4wnyr23mrLXeNEvWciDm8 does not permit cross-origin framing.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter may not like being embedded in a div (which is essentially what fancybox does when left to its default behavior), so I would try adding `type : 'iframe'` to your parameter list.  Especially if Twitter is actually performing a redirect.

Comment: Hey SuperJer! Tried that, saw no difference unfortunately. I am trying to replicate the functionality on this page http://fancy.com/invite. In that page clicking on Twitter opens a popup which directs to Twitter. Once you're there and signed in, the popup closes and control comes back to the main page, where a fancybox appears with the list of your followers.

Comment: Now making a popup to direct me to Twitter is easy, but how is it possible for the popup to close and control to return to the site? I cannot give an answer to this, so I thought to use fancybox (thanks to your suggestion) to handle both steps.

Comment: Ahh, looks like it may need to pop up in its own browser window.  Trouble is, you lose a lot of control of the resulting window.  I understand now what you are trying to accomplish, but I'm afraid I'm out of ideas for your specific issue.